# Convert Date and time with timezone offset into a timestamp using Java

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm trying to convert `2020-11-03T14:03:45.173649-05:00` into timestamp using java.

I tried using `Timestamp.valueOf("2020-11-03T14:03:45.173649-05:00");` here but getting error saying `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]`. Is there any way to convert Date time having timezone offset to timestamp?

Comment: What makes you think that you need an old-fashioned `java.sql.Timestamp`? Since JDBC 4.2 you can parse your string into an `OffsetDateTime` which you can pass directly to `PreparedStatement` and other JDBC classes. The story is longer than I have told it here, but basically you should use java.tiem, the modern Java date and time API and not `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an ISO format, the easiest would be to get an `OffsetDateTime` first and then convert to `Timestamp`:

```
var input = "2020-11-03T14:03:45.173649-05:00";
var odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(input);
var ts = Timestamp.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Alternatively, you can parse the string using a `SimpleDateFormat`.